# set ImageResource is not working

Tags: java, android

I am working with an android project where I send an image name from an activity to another activity, the image is already in the drawable folder, I tried with this code shown below, But it's not working.

**It's working when the code is**

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.someimage);
```

**but i want to display a picture among some pictures that will be decided from another activity, so I need something like below**

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.getIntent().getStringExtra("icon"));
```

How can it be fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the resource Id first.

```
Context context = imageView.getContext();
int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable",
context.getPackageName());
imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

I think in your case `resourceName` would be:

`String resourceName = getIntent().getStringExtra("icon")`

Comment: It's quite strange solution. What is the point of passing String here?

Comment: @muminers The idea is that you may have icon_1, icon_2 ...and so on. An based of some business logic you show different icons. And the app makes logic that generates an appropriate resource name.

Comment: Yes so you can pass resource - R.drawable.icon_1 or R.drawabe.icon_2 - which is exactly what you want. You suggest passing "icon_1", "icon_2" which are just names of those resources, what forces you to do this magical and unsafe casting. It's just pointless

Comment: It`s depends of logic if you have 100 icons, would you like to write manually if(vale==1){return R.drawable.icon_1} ... and that thing 100 times?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put Int to your Intent's Bundle reffering to requested image Resource:

```
intent.putExtra("icon", R.drawable.icon)
```

and then just use it:

```
int imageResource = intent.getIntExtra("icon")
imageView.setImageResource(imageResource);
```

This is much simplier

Comment: I am putting data from a array so no I can't put extras like you say. My extra putting code is : intent.putExtra("type",typeArray[position]);

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution**

```
 Context context = imageView.getContext();
    int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(getIntent().getStringExtra("icon"), "drawable",
            context.getPackageName());
    imageView.setImageResource(id);
```

Comment: Passing String here is boilerplate. It's much easer and more effective to pass Int reffering to resource id.